Cannot POST /api/auth/signup
I'm following a MERN stack course and I've got stuck in middle of a problem. There is no point in completing it before solving this problem, and in my searches I did a thorough inspection and couldn't find the source of the problem. I just added the user sign up and was checking it with Insomnia, according to the following picture:
enter image description here
.
enter image description here
When I used POST is nothing happened
enter image description here
index.js
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import userRouter from './routes/user.routes.js';
import authRouter from './routes/auth.route.js';

dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
    }
); 


app.use('/api/user', userRouter);
app.use('/api/auth', authRouter);

user.controllers.js
export const test = (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Api route is Working!',
    });
};

auth.controller.js
export const signup = (req, res) => {


    console.log(req.body);
};

user.routes.js
import express from 'express';
import {test} from '../controllers/user.controllers.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', test);

export default router;

auth.route.js
import express from 'express';
import { signup } from '../controllers/auth.controller.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', signup);

export default router;

user.model.js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true,   
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true,   
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true,   
    }
}, { timestamps: true});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;

package.json
{
  "name": "docfill-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon api/index.js",
    "start": "node pai/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}


I tried searching for the problem but couldn't find it so I couldn't proceed to the next part.

You might want to remove your mongodb connection string unless you want people to abuse it.

thank you for the advice I've remove it.

Is Insomnia perhaps trying to send the request to the https url instead of the http url?
